# default window for Enter key when accessing overview by the keyboard

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

Within Gnome 41.

If I press <kbd>super</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then  <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I think I am most likely to go to the terminal rather than going to the window under the cursor.
The behaviour can be avoided by pressing Super again.

Is it possible to avoid <kbd>Enter</kbd> going to the cursor-selected window if the Overview was openened through the keyboard and without moving the cursor ?

Thanks